# Saving Changed Features from OpenLayers does not work because GeoServer claims Layer to be read-only

Tags: openlayers-2, geoserver

Trying to save a few changed Features in OpenLayers back to my geoserver (2.4.4) with `saveStrategy.save()`.

Features don’t change. What I get in the geoserver protocol is:
`org.geoserver.wfs.WFSTransactionException: {server.de/myproject}MyLayer is read-only`

What can I do about that? The features definitely have a primary key.

---

I found out, saving features works for other layers, though I don't see any major differences in the WFS xml that I could hold responsible for that.

Comment: First thing to test is if service supports transactions. GeoServer by default does but it can be checked with GetCapabilities. Look at the Operations section `<Operations><Query/><Insert/><Update/><Delete/><Lock/></Operations>`

Comment: `<Operations><Query/><Insert/><Update/><Delete/><Lock/></Operations>` - That's how it looks like. Still, saving does not work. What can I do then?

Comment: Try to check the permissions of the target file. If you use Linux, use `chmod o+rw` to enable writing it, if it is read-only to others (Apache is handled as other).

Comment: What you use as datastore? PostGIS, shapefile, something else?

Comment: I found out that the unix file access right were set incorrectly.